# jQuery File Download - Missing file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [table2CSV](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php) to convert a HTML table to a CSV file with this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('table').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);

    var $button = $("<button type='button'>");
    $button.text("Export to spreadsheet");
    $button.insertAfter($table);

    $button.click(function() {
      var csv = $table.table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
      window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,'
                            + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    });
  });
})
```

All is working correctly but the resulting file is just called 'download'

If I rename it download.csv then it opens correctly, is there a way I can set the filename?

Comment: Check the [src](https://github.com/rubo77/table2CSV/blob/master/table2CSV.js) of table2CSV, it has a `filename` in `option`.

Comment: var csv = $table.table2CSV({delivery:'value',filename:'your file name'});

Comment: Have already tried the filename option from the docs but it isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try to add download attribute to button:

```
 $button[0].setAttribute("download", 'FileName.csv');
```